# Mysql select columns in reverse order ignoring nulls

Tags: mysql

i have a data set like this:
I want to, ignoring null values, select these columns in reverse order.

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
1     2    3    null
1     4   null  null
1    3     5    null
1    null  null null
```

and i want to select it into this:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
3    2    1    null
4   1    null  null
5   3    1     null
1   null null  null
```

is there a good way to do this with a large number of columns?

Comment: There is not really a "good" way to do that on any number of columns.

Comment: As I told you in your last question, if you have a large number of columns like this, your database design is wrong. They should be in separate rows, then you can write queries that don't need to repeat everything for each column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COALESCE()` function and select the column in reverse order with different column alias or name.

```
select coalesce(col3, 0) as col1,
coalesce(col2, 0) as col2,
coalesce(col1, 0) as col3,
col4
from your_table;
```